# Android studio pause and resume countdown timer for progress bar

Tags: android-studio, timer, progress-bar, countdowntimer

I am using a countdown timer which updates my progress bar which decreases from 100 (full) to 0(empty) but when the app is paused would like to pause the timer and then restart it upon resuming the app. I implement the count down timer like so:

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {


    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 100);
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameOver.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

And in my on create:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_screen);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.timerBar);
    progressBar.setProgress(100);
    myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(10000, 10);
    myCountDownTimer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a boolean in your **MyCountDownTimer** class that will change in the `onPause` and `onResume` methods of your **Activity**. Check the `// ADDED` comments to see the changes you have to make to make this work.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_screen);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.timerBar);
        progressBar.setProgress(100);
        myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(10000, 10);
        myCountDownTimer.start();
    }

   // ADDED
   @Override
   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
       myCountDownTimer.pause();
   }

   // ADDED
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
       myCountDownTimer.resume();
   }

}


public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    // ADDED
    private boolean pause;

    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    // ADDED
    public void pause() {
        pause = true;
    }

    // ADDED
    public void resume() {
        pause = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        int progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 100);

        // ADDED
        if (!pause) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // ADDED
        isRunning = false;

        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameOver.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works however the countdown timer is still running in the background and will end the activity upon reaching 0

Comment: Ohh didn't thought about that. What you can do is : save the timer value when you pause it, cancel the current timer and finally restart a new timer with the remaining time. You can save the remaining time in the `onTick(...)` Method. When you create your timer set a low `countDownInterval` for more precision.